# Show labels of a KML file in Google Earth

Tags: labeling, kml, google-earth

I have a KML file created from an Excel spreadsheet which contains name, lat and long. How can I display the name in Google Earth?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what app. you used to create the kml from the excel file but in simplistic terms you will need to embed a **name** tag within a **Placemark** tag to show label for each point, see example xml below (label in this example is "Untitled Placemark"):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>test.kml</name>
    <StyleMap id="m_ylw-pushpin">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
        <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.3</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pushpin/ylw-pushpin.png</href>
            </Icon>
            <hotSpot x="20" y="2" xunits="pixels" yunits="pixels"/>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
        <name>Untitled Placemark</name>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-122.2109720652407</longitude>
            <latitude>41.31147768821823</latitude>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <heading>-9.207431002912404e-008</heading>
            <tilt>44.99911020701676</tilt>
            <range>176757.1969144266</range>
            <gx:altitudeMode>relativeToSeaFloor</gx:altitudeMode>
        </LookAt>
        <styleUrl>#m_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <gx:drawOrder>1</gx:drawOrder>
            <coordinates>-122.3283130204979,41.24737300737706,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

You may open up the kml in a text editor to add or edit tags.

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked long long ago, but I just had the same problem. The solution for me was to change the name of the columns to names that GE understands. If I understood correctly you can choose one column to be the title and another column to be the description. So I named one column `Name` (this will be displayed as the title) and the other column I named `description`. This is how GE understands that these should be the labels.